# Errors when importing project

Tags: android, eclipse, import

When I try to import an Android project in Eclipse, I get tons of errors once imported in workstation.

Any recommendation on how to fix this? I tried:

- project > clean
- import > general > existing project
- Import > android > existing project

None of them worked for me.

Picture:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check if the build path contains all the libraries used by the project (tipically the ones in /libs)

Comment: Is this a decompiled source code?

Comment: No it is not decompiled source code

Answer (score 0):

When I copied and pasted all of my workspaces onto another computer I got confused by similar errors.

Turned out that the external JARs I had manually added were in a different file location on the original computer than they were on the new one.

Updated the locations and all was well again.

Might be worth a shot?

Comment: Seems Did not worked for me . steps 1 = in libs menu  right click the .jar file (only one jar file was present their ) And Then Build was present and then build path > add build path . And then refreshed the project No luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using the library Project as either references(Properties-> Android) or as jar files(properties-> java build path -> libraries). Dont use them as both.

Comment: Tried it Did not helped .

Comment: DId you install the adt  separately. If you have downloaded the integrated package that doesnt work sometimes

Comment: I installed All In one package . Here Is picture of Installed Kit http://oi41.tinypic.com/21s9so.jpg

Comment: Install eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and then install the eclipse plugin. follow these steps http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html, after this import your project in this. I hope this works